Are high-energy neutrinos subject of relativistic time dilation like muons are?
Synchrotron experiments and cosmic-rays hitting our atmosphere have proved many times that high-energy massive muons moving with speeds close to the speed of light are subject to relativistic length contraction and time dilation effects.
I am asking since neutrinos are massive particles moving at speed very close to the speed of light, if these would be also subject to time dilation effect and if we could use this to our advantage to measure the actual mass of neutrinos in an experiment?

There will always be a difference in the rate of passage of time as measured by two clocks with a relative velocity between them. This includes for relativistic neutrinos. However, this is not directly related to mass in any way. These effects would need to be accounted for in oscillation measurements, though.

What makes you think that this wouldnt apply to neutrinos? Time dilation is a property of spacetime itself.

Direct neutrino-mass measurement based on 259 days of KATRIN data https://arxiv.org/abs/2406.13516

Do you have in mind any particular way that time dilation can help measure mass more accurately, and in the case of neutrinos in particular? Or, are you just asking whether time dilation helps measure mass of particles with relativistic speeds more accurately in general? It's currently not very clear...

Your question is based on a common misunderstanding of length contraction (and time dilation). The reason it's common is because how introductory relativity is often presented. For example:
The speed-of-light is the speed limit because as you approach $c$, you gain mass and it requires infinite energy; moreover, time slows down and you shrink in the direction of motion.
I don't like this because it implies you can move relative to space: if you pick the rest frame where you have the lowest energy, fastest clock and longest length: boom, you have found the absolute rest frame.
The whole point of special relativity is that there is no absolute rest frame, and for any inertial frame (which includes that of a neutrino): $c$ is $c$ in all directions in all inertial frames.
Time dilation and length contraction occur in other frames that are moving with respect to the initial frame. For example, right now you're moving very close to $c$ in the frame of an UHECR. You're 2 nanometers tall, and you clock takes 30 years to tick 1 second. Yet it has no effect on you.
Same for neutrinos. It's at rest in its own frame and does not care about our coordinates describing it.
Now a wave packet in an energy eigenstate $E_n$ propagates in time with a rotating phase $e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}$, which gets tricky because we make neutrinos in flavor eigenstates, and the propagate as 3 mass eigenstate.
Regarding time-dilation, you estimate the Lorentz factor since:
$$ \gamma = \frac{\gamma m c^2}{mc^2} = \frac E {mc^2} $$
Now Chat GPT says the DUNE neutrino energy is "ghostlike particles at nearly the speed of light with more than 1,000 scientists" and the AI is giving the mass in kg. idk, seems useless, but you can go forward and figure out how time-dilated they are. You'll approximations if you're using floating point:
With $c=1$:
$$ \gamma = \frac E m =\frac 1 {\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}$$
$$\approx 
\frac 1 {\sqrt{2(1-\beta)}}
$$
and:
$$ \beta \approx  1 - \frac 1 {2\gamma^2} $$

why are you suddenly referring to ChatGPT at all?

@naturallyInconsistent good question. So when I search "DUNE beam energy" I get an AI result whether I want it or not. I was simply unable to get a straight answer from the search. I even went with the "normal" search algo results, and read and read, and still: no beam energy. It was extremely annoying, and when I refined the tokens for the AI it just flubbed it and produced trash, so who am I going to tell? All youz guys, that's who. Try it yourself, and let me know what the energy range is, and: can you avoid AI completely?

Strangely enough, half of the physics community has opposing views on this, namely many say that constant speed SR time dilation effects in the rest frame of an relativistically   moving massive object are physical real thus all virtual photons exchange between the atoms of  a mass object are time dilated inside its rest frame and therefore aging slows down compared to an external non-relativistic moving observer.  So for an astronaut moving at about 0.87c (i.e. γ=2) will age  half the years relative to a stationary observer on Earth.

The only real rest frame is the speed of light c in the vacuum according to SR.

@Markoul11 the virtual photons I used to use at work had more momentum than they had energy, so I don't know what they thought about time dilation.

Yes. This will affect how fast they oscillate among different flavors, and how far they travel as they do so. Experiments such as DUNE need to take this into account.
For more on neutrinos, see the Even Bananas series of videos from Fermilab. They are all good, but you might start with 1 and 2. 10 is of particular interest, as it explains oscillations.
For DUNE, you might look at What is the DUNE experiment? by Don Lincoln, another Fermilab physicist. He has his own sets of videos, such as these.
